# how to check different div tags show same values using jquery

Tags: jquery

In two different `div` tags under HTML checkboxes are 1st div tag check box check the value display the some data and 2nd div tag checkbox click checkbox then automatically hide the 1st div tag using jQuery help me

TIA

Comment: Can you please provide some code which you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like below please correct me if I am wrong

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#firstDiv').change(function(){
       $('.testContent').show(500);
    });
      
    $('#secDiv').change(function(){
      $('.testContent').hide(400);
    });
 });
```

```css
.testContent {
  display:none;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="testContent">
   Demo Text
</div>

Test 1<input id="firstDiv" type="checkbox"/> 

Test 2<input id="secDiv" type="checkbox" />
```

Comment: Thanks Yogesh .. Actually my requirment is Student table under these fields are name,Branch,Location  under branch contains 4 check boxes are CSE,IT,Mech,Civil and Location Contains check boxes are Hyd,Mumbai,Delhi,Kolkatta  Branch check the checkbox get the values and Location field check the checkbox get the values but Branch checkbox is checked and Location Checkbox is checked some times uncheck the Location checkbox how to display Branch details  Branch fields are one div tag Location is different div tag how to write code for Jquery  TIA

Comment: Hello @RaviGuntreddi I asm still not clear on your requirement

Comment: how to show data on check and un check on multiple div tags using jquery

Comment: Hai Yogesh i have small requirment  1 to 100 check boxes in my application i am not input to 100 checkboxes i want to bind 100 checkboxes in array list type TIA

Comment: Ok so what is your requirement?

Comment: Please give me your code I can help you to achieve this, provide me html, css and JS I'll give implement it and will give you

Comment: <section name="Location" class="checkBoxListForLocation" id="checkBoxListForLocation">
                                    <input type="checkbox" class="single-checkbox" name="checkBoxListForLocation" value="Hyderabad">Hyderabad</input><br />      <input type="checkbox" class="single-checkbox" name="checkBoxListForLocation" value="Banglore">Banglore</input>   ... 100  checkboxes</section> i want code for JS TIA

Comment: Hai Yogesh ... see this link http://www.makaan.com/hyderabad-property/kukatpally-property/residential-property-for-sale-in-hyderabad/search-properties .  u see Projects menu under search button search on check box items display checkbox items  this is my requirement  how to dispaly same functionality i want to code using JS and Html TIA